# Different length scale per dimension in TensorFlow

Tags: regression, tensorflow

I would like to know how to use a different length scale in a kernel for each dimension of the input. For instance, take an input of dimension 4, I would like to use 4 different length scales where for each coordinate of the input.
That is, take the Gaussian Kernel (see https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/math/psd_kernels/ExponentiatedQuadratic) for example, I want to define the kernel $k$ as
$k(x,y) = exp(- (\frac{(x_1 - y_1)^2}{\gamma_1^2} + \frac{(x_2 - y_2)^2}{\gamma_2^2}))$ instead of $k(x,y) = exp(- \frac{||x - y||^2}{\gamma^2})$ where $x = (x_1, x_2)$ and $y = (y_1, y_2)$.

Comment: Does anything prevent you from initially dividing coordinate $i$ by $\gamma_i$ and proceeding with unit scales?

Comment: Well, actually, it is a very good idea. I will try doing it. Thanks.

Comment: @whuber unfortunately, often code is factored in a way where kernels are created in one place and applied in another. So the hyperparameters of the kernel are not always available to divide coordinates. I'll answer the question below.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use a feature transformation that scales the coordinates, and use a unit length scale.

```py
# Define your length scales.

# For example, for a 3-dimensional feature vector:
length_scale = jnp.asarray([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])

# Create the kernel.
base_kernel = tfp.math.psd_kernels.MaternOneHalf(amplitude=1.0, length_scale=None) # None <=> 1
kernel = tfp.math.psd_kernels.FeatureTransformed(base_kernel,
                                                 transformation_fn=lambda x, _1, _2: x / length_scale)
X = jnp.ones((4, 3))
K = kernel.matrix(X, X)
print(K.shape)  # (4, 4)
```